# Вопрос по WinAPI: Как ограничить перемещение курсора мыши областью открытого окна?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Столкнулся с проблемой: при выполнении программы, мне необходимо, чтобы курсор рандомно менял свое местоположение при нажатии клавиш, что главное, в **ПРЕДЕЛАХ ОБЛАСТИ ОКНА**, однако курсор все равно появляется, там, где ему захочется(изредка попадает в пределы окна). Это не смотря на то, что используется функция *ScreenToClient()*, которая должна решать эту проблему, но, почему-то, она ее не решает. Прилагаю часть кода и скрин самого окна.

```
case WM_CHAR: 
        //перемещение курсора
        srand(time(NULL));
        POINT lpPoint;
        do {
            lpPoint.x = rand();
        } while (lpPoint.x > GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN));
        do {
            lpPoint.y = rand();
        } while (lpPoint.y > GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN));
        ScreenToClient(hWnd, (LPPOINT)&lpPoint);
        SetCursorPos(lpPoint.x, lpPoint.y);
        break;
```

[image: Результат выполнения программы и область, в рамках которой должен находиться курсор]

Comment: замените `GetSystemMetrics` на [`GetWindowRect`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowrect) либо [`GetClientRect`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getclientrect)

Comment: поменял на: case WM_CHAR: //перемещение курсора srand(time(NULL)); RECT lpRect; GetClientRect(hWnd, &lpRect); POINT lpPoint; do { lpPoint.x = rand(); } while (lpPoint.x < lpRect.left && lpPoint.x > lpRect.right); do { lpPoint.y = rand(); } while (lpPoint.y < lpRect.bottom && lpPoint.y > lpRect.top); ScreenToClient(hWnd, &lpPoint); SetCursorPos(lpPoint.x, lpPoint.y); break;  Однако теперь курсор всегда уходит в правый нижний угол.

Comment: Координата не может быть одновременно меньше нуля и больше стороны прямоугольника. Внимательно изучите документацию по ссылке.

Answer (score 0):

Оставлю код:

```
//код...
GetWindowRect(hWnd,&rc);
ClipCursor(&rc);
//код...
```

Возможно он вам поможет. Функция `Clipcursor`  ограничивает мышь в определённой области, поэтому аккуратней с ней.
Для того чтобы остановить ограничение мыши надо вызвать эту функцию с параметром `NULL`

```
ClipCursor(NULL);
```